# DD4T.Web dll is missing in DD4T.MVC package when downloaded from NuGet

Tags: dd4t-2

When I tried upgrade the DD4T version recently I see that DD4T.MVC5 NuGet package does not contain DD4T.Web DLL. We are using Dynamic resource management from DD4T.Web.Whether this is getting discontinued? or Is there a different implementation for this class in DD4T?

Comment: That DLL should definitely be included in the package. Which version have you downloaded?

Comment: I have downloaded DD4T.MVC5 2.2.6 version and i do not see DD4T.Web dll. then I have upgraded to 2.2.7 and i see the DLLs fine there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, version 2.2.6 of the NuGet packages DD4T.MVC4 and DD4T.MVC5 is missing the DD4T.Web.dll.
I have deprecated these versions right away. Upgrading to the latest stable release (2.2.7 at the moment) is indeed the solution.

Comment: Thanks Quirijn! there is one more issue with other nuget package. XmlSerializers is missing in DD4T.Model 2.2.3 if you help fixing this as well then it’s great!

Comment: If you mean DD4T.ContentModel.XmlSerializers.dll, that is present in DD4T.Model 2.2.3. If you have an issue with this, could you ask a new question about it please?

Comment: I do not see DD4T.ContentModel.XmlSerializers in DD4T.Model 2.2.3 package. Let me raise this in new question as suggested.